# Currency Switcher

Tags: currency

I have got currency switch dropdown set up on header.phtml and its working fine and changing the currency correctly but its keep redirecting back to home page every time I switched the currency. How can I prevent it from going back to home page and stay in current page after page reload?

in my browser this url was 302 before I get redirected to home page
http://myshop//directory/currency/switch/currency/USD/uenc/aHR0cDovL... 
302 moved temporarily

Answer (score 2):

Basically,magento is change the currency at `Mage_Directory_CurrencyController` on `switchAction()` function.

And using `_redirectReferer()` is redirect to `previous page`.

May the `REFERER  url getRefererUrl()` is not working  thus magento `redirect to home page` .

And as send a  `site url` has been send as option url for  redirection after currency change thus it redirect to home page.

see `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action` on  function.

```
 protected function _redirectReferer($defaultUrl=null)
    {

        $refererUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl();
        if (empty($refererUrl)) {
            $refererUrl = empty($defaultUrl) ? Mage::getBaseUrl() : $defaultUrl;
        }

        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($refererUrl);
        return $this;
    }
```

**Solution:**

you need check  previous page url  value by adding code:

```
    $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape( $this->getRequest()->getParam('uenc')) );
```

at `Mage_Directory_CurrencyController`. it should be give you previous page url

Comment: Yea I am also digging into the core code and saw this but how to replace with $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getBaseUrl()); to user current url ?

Comment: is there a core magento function that get current url? 
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); i'm not sure but gonna give this a try

Comment: I am not seeing this code  $refererUrl = Mage::helper('core')->urlDecodeAndEscape( $this->getRequest()->getParam('uenc')) ); at Mage_Directory_CurrencyController at app/code/Mage/Directory/controllers/CurrencyController.php

Comment: just add this code and check your refere url is right or wrong

Comment: I found the problem its actually magneto base64_decode returning blank

Comment: in /app/code/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php url encode function is working fine but url decode function seems not returning anything